# timespec_get functionality for C++03

Tags: c++03

I have the following code working on C++17, but I need the same functionality in C++03. How can I accomplish this?

```
return timespec_get(ts, 0) == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`timespec_get` and the associated `timespec` structure are, largely, an adoption from POSIX's timespec functions. See 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/timespec_get and [the time.h header definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/time.h.html).

So, if your compiler and environment is POSIX capable, it suffices to call the equivalent function from `time.h`.

If you don't have a POSIX environment available you'll have to approximate the results from other functions available in your environment. On Windows, you can use the GetSystemTime family of functions for example.

For example implementations, [I did provide timespec_get emulation as part of the cxxomfort library](http://ryan.gulix.cl/fossil.cgi/cxxomfort/artifact/9f2b962a97cb6c8c), precisely for a number of compilers as far back as C++03 mode, and I confirmed it to work with VC 2008 and 2010 as well as the OpenWatcom 2 betas.